# ExtJS grid form with document in MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, extjs

I have a grid whith the data that come from a database. Each row of the grid containt these fields : document name, owner, version etc. The content of the document is in a blob.

I want, when the user double-click on a row, to download the content of the document. The best way will be a pop-up that ask a confirmation. The grid must stay on the screen.

I'm able to read the content of the document with an ajax request and put the result in a variable.

```
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                            url: '../controleurs/c_get_doc_content.php',
                            method: 'POST',
                            params: { dep: r.data.nom_document },
                            success: function(response, opts) {console.log(response);console.log(opts)},
                            requestcomplete: function (conn, response, options) {},
                            failure: function() {console.log('failure');},
                            headers: { 'my-header': 'foo' },
```

How can I save the content of the document to a file on the user PC ?

Comment: How can you possibly have a blob in JS? You mean a base 64 encoded blob?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is server side. Instead of passing the blob to the JS, you just pass an ID. Then when the user chooses to download the file, you call the server and it returns a document that can be downloaded.

You would just stream that content as an attachment instead of sending it with the AJAX request

in PHP you use the following code to make sure a file is downloaded and the save as dialog is displayed.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this : You would just stream that content as an attachment instead of sending it with the AJAX request.

Comment: You are sending the attachment as a base64 encoded string within the AJAX response. Instead of doing that, send just an attachment id with the AJAX response. When you actually want to download the file, user clicks some link, you request download.php?id=IdFromAjax, using a standard request, not AJAX. Your download.php would use the code I pasted above as an example.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think that I have more to learn about standard request. Also, the file is in the database not in a directory.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the file is, download.php can just read it from the database and output it to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Set the content type of your PHP response to something the browser would want to save....